# How to create an object for a class with T inside if statement

Tags: java

I want to create on object based on a condition such that:

```java
SemMeasure<SuiteClass> semObj = new SemMeasure<>(items);
semObj.calcDif();
semObj.measureDiv();
semObj.writeData();
.... // other things to do based on semObj
```

The if-statement is:

```java
if (Type == "suite") {
    SemMeasure<SuiteClass> semObj = new SemMeasure<>(items);
    semObj.calcDif();
    semObj.measureDiv();
    semObj.writeData();
    .... // other things to do based on semObj 
} else if (Type == "case") {
    SemMeasure<CaseClass> semObj = new SemMeasure<>(items); // here the difference
    semObj.calcDif();
    semObj.measureDiv();
    semObj.writeData();
    .... // other things to do based on semObj 
}
```

The difference is only in the type of T that is either `SuiteClass` or `CaseClass`.

Instead of repeating the code with the two conditions, is there a way to only make the if changes the class type (changing `SuiteClass` to `CaseClass` or vise versa)?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create one interface with some methods and implement it in several classes. Then you don't need `if` statement, just call methods of these classes:

```java
public class Test {
    public interface SuiteCase {
        void calcDif();
    }

    public static class Suite implements SuiteCase {
        @Override
        public void calcDif() {
            System.out.println("Suite");
        }
    }

    public static class Case implements SuiteCase {
        @Override
        public void calcDif() {
            System.out.println("Case");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SuiteCase suiteCase1 = new Suite();
        SuiteCase suiteCase2 = new Case();

        suiteCase1.calcDif(); // Suite
        suiteCase2.calcDif(); // Case
    }
}
```